# Is the weight of authorship valuable?

Tags: publications, authorship

Some professors publish their papers alone or with a single postdoc/PhD student. In this case, he/she should spend lots of time as a sole or second author.

Some professors publish the same kind of paper by several postdoc/PhD students and international collaborations. He/she is one of say 10 authors who have contributed to the paper. Thus, he/she needs much less time for publishing a paper.

In the latter case, they can publish much more papers. On the other hand, the papers attract more attention as each of 10 authors promote the paper.

I wonder if there is any value/credit for the former scheme? Or it is waste of time, and all professors should adopt the latter scheme as much he/she can?

Comment: It's not that one chooses an authorship scheme on purpose, it's the type of work that decides the scheme. I have all multi-author papers, and those papers would never have been written as single-author papers because no one would have had the expertise, the time and the equipment to do the work alone.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano while your point is correct to some extent, it is also a matter of personal preference. Some prefer to work with more people and some do not. In many papers, international collaborations are not vital. The experiments are usually done in one institution and the rest is just a consult. This can be well seen when a semi-retired eminent scientist appears in many papers. The papers benefit from a consult, but it is not necessary. Some like it some don't.

Comment: What do you mean by "value/credit"? Academia isn't a game where the goal is to be a coauthor on as many papers as possible. Somebody whose CV consists of 50 single-authored papers will be evaluated *differently* from somebody whose CV consists of 200 papers with 20 authors each, but you can't say that one is better than the other. It is also field-dependent.

Comment: The number of authors doesn't tell you anything about how much each of them contributed to the paper.

Comment: It may be quicker with less co-authors.  For example, managing contributions to the paper and ensuring everybody is happy with the final text is much easier with 2 or 3 people at one institute, than with 10+ spread over several institutes.